# Lubridate Objects Masked After Loading Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

When I load the `data.table` package after having already loaded the `lubridate` package, I get the following error message:

```
Loading required package: data.table
data.table 1.9.4 For help type: ?data.table
*** NB: by=.EACHI is now explicit. See README to restore previous behaviour.

Attaching package: ‘data.table’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:lubridate’:

hour, mday, month, quarter, wday, week, yday, year
```

Does anyone know a) what's causing this issue and b) how to prevent these objects within `lubridate` from being masked?

**UPDATE**:

The issue associated with the above is that I'm using the `quarter` function from the `lubridate` package and, after loading the `data.table` package, I can no longer do so in the same way.

Specifically, when I run `quarter(Date, with_year=TRUE)` (where `Date` is a vector of class = Dates), I now get the following error: `Error in quarter(Date, with_year = TRUE) : unused argument (with_year = TRUE)`.

If I simply, `quarter(Date)`, then I can get the desired output without the attached year. For example, if `Date` is set as simply May 15, 2015 (today), then `quarter(Date)` will yield `2` (since we're in the 2nd quarter of 2015), but I'd like it to yield `2015.2`, hence the importance of the `with_year = TRUE` option.

Obviously, I can overcome this by using `paste` to bind together the year and the output of `quarter(Date)`, but I'd prefer to avoid that work-around.

Comment: You should explain why this is a problem. Masking usually means that the package is providing _more_ functionality, not less.

Comment: @BondedDust But sometimes, you get _different_ fonctionality. And this situation leads to issues.

Comment: Right.... sometimes issues. ... but which issues .... we need specificity. What exactly is the problem? I'm guessing this is just a user who has no idea what masking does and has done no research on the terminology. Do you have a better theory? Feel free to post an answer. I edited the tags to remove the  specificity to either of the particular packages because it is generic to all R packages. Do explain NAMESPACEs while you are at it.

Comment: My close vote was for lack of clarity, but I could imagine other votes being for "why isn't this code working" ... although there is nothing that is actually not working.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've edited my original question to reflect why I wouldn't want this to occur. Let me know if there is remaining ambiguity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An object name in a package namespace is masked when a new object is defined with the same name. This can be done by the user assigning the name, or by attaching another package that has an object of the same name.

`data.table` and `lubridate` have overlapping function names. If you want the `lubridate` version to be the default, then the easiest solution is to load `data.table` first, then load `lubridate`---thus it will be the `data.table` versions of these functions that is masked by the "newer" `lubridate` versions.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
```

Otherwise, the solution is to use `::` (as in `package::function`) to fully specify which version of the function you want to use, for example:

```
lubridate::quarter(Date, with_year = T)
```

Another option, which involves a little less typing but is perhaps a little less clear as well, would be to alias the lubridate functions you want in the global environment at the start of your script.

```
quarter = lubridate::quarter
```

Any use of `quarter()` later in the script will use the `lubridate` version of the function.

Yet another option is the `conflicted` package, which provides a system for preferring a function from one package. It is a bit more intense and intentional, you should definitely read the documentation before using it, but your script might include something like this:

```
library(conflicted)
conflict_prefer("quarter", "lubridate")
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `conflicted` provides various alternatives and is a good practice to use it while loading libraries to be clear on the masking.
https://github.com/r-lib/conflicted [image: Picture from Hadley's twitter feed]